# Writing on Hyper terminal using WinCE device

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-ce

ia m trying to read/ write on hyper terminal using winCE device. iam able to write the data on Terminal from device but not able to read the data from terminal to device. Even afer writing on terminal , Hyper terminal is also not accepting text from keyboard.
i am using basic Communication API's  for reading and writing(ReadFile() and WriteFile().write file is working but not able to write new line on terminal already tried with \r\n). please suggest any poiner regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps post your code?   I assume you're using the Windows API (since you mention ReadFile() and MFC).    There could be all sorts of reasons why data is not being read into the device.